# Triangle Center Midpoint

Tags: geometry, triangles

Consider the following construction of a triangle center: (The method could also be easily generalized to any shape with finite perimeter)

For each point $X$ on the triangle, find point $X'$ such that $X$ and $X'$ split the triangle into two sections of equal length (each of length equal to the triangle semiperimeter). Then, let $Y$ be the midpoint of $X$ and $X'$. The locus of all such $Y$ is also triangular, so we can repeat the process on the triangle created by the locus of all such $Y$, ad infinitum until the triangles converge to a point.

Through some computer simulation, I was able to determine that this convergence point isn't one of the common triangle centers. Searching through the [Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html), I also wasn't able to find this triangle center listed. Does this center have an established name, or is there literature available on the topic?

Comment: My experience with [this triangle center](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1104038/35416) suggest that such recursively defined centers are likely not algebraic, while most if not all centers in the ETC seem to have an algebraic description (i.e. in terms of a bunch of polynomials). I also compared the point resulting from 5 steps of your construction against the corresponding ETC coordinates, and found no match either. Since the triangles quickly approache a regular one, truncating the iteration so soon seems justified.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can be more specific: "The locus of all such $Y$" isn't just any triangle; its vertices are those $Y$s corresponding to $X$s at the vertices of the original triangle. As [a preliminary proposition in this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179553/409) shows, the construction of the perimeter bisector through a triangle's vertex is geometrically straightforward; therefore, so is the construction of your locus triangle. Algebraically, it seems like something of a mess, even for one iteration. (I think the ratio of new sides to old may be interesting, however.)

Comment: BTW: Browsing the ETC's "Nagel Point" entry, I'm reminded that the perimeter bisectors through a triangle's vertices meet points of tangency with the triangle's excircles. So, their construction is a bit more straightforward than my "preliminary proposition" indicates. (Perhaps I should update that other answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer, but information that may help lead to one.

---

With the help of Mathematica to push some symbols, I've determined that the coordinates of the "Draksis Triangle" $\triangle A^\prime B^\prime C^\prime$ is obtained from those of $\triangle ABC$ thusly:

$$\begin{align}
A^\prime &= \frac{1}{2}\;A + \frac{\cos(\beta/2) \sin(\gamma/2)}{2\cos(\alpha/2)}\;B + \frac{\sin(\beta/2)\cos(\gamma/2)}{2\cos(\alpha/2)}\;C \\[4pt]
B^\prime &= \frac{\sin(\gamma/2)\cos(\alpha/2)}{2\cos(\beta/2)}\;A + \frac{1}{2}\;B + \frac{\cos(\gamma/2) \sin(\alpha/2)}{2\cos(\beta/2)}\;C \\[4pt]
C^\prime &= \frac{\cos(\alpha/2) \sin(\beta/2)}{2\cos(\gamma/2)}\;A + \frac{\sin(\alpha/2)\cos(\beta/2)}{2\cos(\gamma/2)}\;B + \frac{1}{2}\;C
\end{align}$$
where $\alpha := \angle BAC$, $\beta := \angle CBA$, $\gamma := \angle ACB$.

Here are some metrics of the Draksis Triangle: 
$$a^\prime = a\sin(\beta/2) \sin(\gamma/2) \qquad
b^\prime = b\sin(\gamma/2) \sin(\alpha/2) \qquad
c^\prime = c\sin(\alpha/2) \sin(\beta/2)$$

$$\alpha^\prime = \frac{\pi - \alpha}{2} \qquad
\beta^\prime = \frac{\pi - \beta}{2} \qquad
\gamma^\prime = \frac{\pi - \gamma}{2}$$

where $a := |\overline{BC}|$ and $a^\prime := |\overline{B^\prime C^\prime}|$, etc. Note that the angle formula confirms @MvG's assertion that iterated Draksis triangles converge on an equilateral: If $\alpha = \frac13\pi + \theta$, then $\alpha^\prime = \frac13\pi - \frac12\theta$.

Iterating the construction to get at the "Draksis Point" seems daunting, but given the relations above, there may yet be hope.